# node.js doesn't log errors in test environment

Tags: node.js, express

I have a little node.js/express.js app that I'm running in `test environment`. I'm just wondering why node.js doesn't log errors.

In `development environment` I can see errors.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cardValue' of null
```

I've added this code but it's not enough.

```
var express           = require('express'),    
    app               = module.exports = express(),
    server            = require('http').Server(app),
    logger            = require('morgan'),
    methodOverride    = require('method-override'),
    bodyParser        = require('body-parser'),
    multer            = require('multer'),
    errorHandler      = require('errorhandler');

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || Config.service.port);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(multer());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);
    next();
});
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV); // it prints test
if ('development' == app.get('env') || 'test' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(errorHandler({ log : true}));
}
server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Ronda.as server listening on port " + app.get('port') + " " + app.get('env'));
});
```

Comment: What does `errorHandler` do?

Comment: It's the buit-in error handler for Express.js

Comment: Can you update the question with your script that initializes the server?

Comment: Done. It's a very classic code. Is there any way to tell to node.js to log all errors in the test environment as well ?

Comment: Are you sure that `$NODE_ENV` is set to `test`?

Comment: Yeah sure. I've added a `console.log` to be sure

Comment: the error is not from the errorHandler middleware. You can remove it, and there will be still no errors in test environment :/ I dont know how to fix it too.
Did you find the solution maybe?

Answer (score 0):

[The fine manual](https://github.com/expressjs/errorhandler#log) states:

> **log**
>
> Provide a function to be called with the error and a string representation of the error.
>
> ...
>
> *The default value for this option is true unless `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'`*

In other words, the default for `errorhandler` is to not log anything when `$NODE_ENV` equals `test`.

To fix, use this to force it to log:

```
app.use(errorHandler({ log : true }));
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I still get errors logs just in dev environment.

Comment: You should post the actual code you're using, because as it is now, it won't work anyway (you have your own error handler already and I don't think that Express allows for multiple error handlers, for one).

Comment: Code updated. I'm not using my own error handler. I'm using the one provided by `errorhandler` package. Should I use multiple error handlers ?

Comment: @hamou92 this: `app.use(function (err, req, res, next) { ... })` is an error handler.

Comment: I've deleted my own one. Still don't get errors in test environment.